# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath not called

Tags: tableview

I have a added a view from a view controller which presents a UITableView as a subview in the parent view controller.

I have set the delegate and data source of the table view to be the controller that has the view.

When I select cells on the table view, I get into didSelectRowAtIndexPath and I am able to push the next view onto the navigation controller.  So data source and delegate seem to be working.

The accessory button does not work however.  accessoryView is nil for the cell and the accessoryType is set to UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton when i return the cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I get the delete button when I swipe to the left but that doesn't work when I touch it either.  The cell works fine however.

The only thing unusual is that I am instantiating the view controller with the table view from a different storyboard than the initial one I use for the app.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add the essential parts of your code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check UIttableview editing rows delegates

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

NSString *stringToMove = weekDaySchedule [sourceIndexPath.row];
[weekDaySchedule removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
[weekDaySchedule insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

[self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

[weekDaySchedule removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];    }
editingStyle = NO;
}
```